# How does this quiz gets its answers when offline?

Tags: javascript, html, web, google-chrome-devtools

This follows on from my post: [How would I find the answer to this quiz using inspect element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55323478/how-would-i-find-the-answer-to-this-quiz-using-inspect-element)

I'm trying to find out where the answers to a quiz on a quiz website are stored. The website is able to evaluate my answer as correct or incorrect even when I'm offline. I've used the network tab on inspect element to see incoming and outgoing requests.

https://sendvid.com/f9r1h35y

From the video above you see that I am able to see the questions and data related to them. However, I still don't see the answers with the questions.

It looks as if a request is made to an API for the answer. However, I don't understand how that would work when there is no internet. The video below is me experimenting a little bit more. https://sendvid.com/f9r1h35y

I appreciate all the help I can get. If you need any more info, please ask.

Comment: Are you able to identify the API request that downloads all of the questions? I'm struggling to see the data from the video unfortunately... Do any of the responses look to contain any of the questions you see?

Comment: Better question, can you get results of your quiz once you're offline? or do you need to be online again to get your answers validated? I don't see how anyone in their right minds would keep the answers on the client as it's usually done on the server. Most college quiz system I used you could take it offline but you still need a connection to submit for processing.

Comment: @Andrei you get an instant result on each question, whether if it is correct or not. See the video: https://sendvid.com/rdsiuun7.

Comment: @DanGardner this is the data from the request. https://pastebin.com/y8HbUhn1. Now that I think about it, I'm not 100% sure whether it is calling for the answer. I think it might be sending data about how the question was answered (correct or incorrect). The website allows you to review previous quizzes.